# It's possible to change the header for a custom component? (react navigation)

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5

I am using reaction navigation, I would like to have my own header component (it is very specific).

In the publication it says that it is possible to change the title or the title of something personalized, but is it possible to change the header for another component?
**I thought about doing something like that**

```
<App.Screen
  name="Scan"
  component={Scan}
  options={{ header: (props) => <MyCustomComponent {...props} /> }}
/>
```